AngleSharp does not find element using selector
Can anyone explain why this code does not find the <div /> element?
I am using AngleSharp.
string html = "<div class=\"styles__Accordion___blue\"><h1>Hello</h1></div>";
    
HtmlParser p = new HtmlParser();
var f = p.ParseFragment(html, null);
var e = f.QuerySelector("div [class^='styles__Accordion___']");


Your selector is wrong, you need to remove the space after div:
var e = f.QuerySelector("div[class^='styles__Accordion___']");

And with that, it works.
